# Can you set medium columns on Zurb Foundation 4?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, zurb-foundation

**NB: This has been asked but not really answered here: [How do I make use of breakpoints in Zurb foundation 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030973/how-do-i-make-use-of-breakpoints-in-zurb-foundation-4)**

The **small** and **large** columns on Foundation 4 are really handy, but **small** activates perhaps a little earlier than I'd like - is there any way of setting a **medium-columns** setting for smallish but not tiny resolutions, e.g. 800 * 600?

In my specific case, I'd like the following setup:

```
 <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-4 columns">First column</div>
 <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-8 columns">Second column</div>
```

Comment: hey, i'm looking for the same thing to have a medium columns or types of medium columns betwenn large and small and i came up across a link today http://adioso.com/blog/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Foundation has transitioned to version 5, there is now simply a medium grid, which you can access using `medium-12 columns` etc.

Answer (score 7):

In Zurb Foundation 4 I have added medium to my grid columns with the following. Just add this after the @import of your foundation globals and grid.

```
@if $include-html-grid-classes != false {

  /* Styles for screens that are atleast 768px and max width 1024px */
  @media #{$small} and (max-width: 1024px) {

    @for $i from 1 through $total-columns {
      .medium#{-$i} { @include grid-column($columns:$i,$collapse:null,$float:false); }
    }

    @for $i from 0 through $total-columns - 1 {
      .row .medium-offset-#{$i} { @include grid-column($offset:$i, $collapse:null,$float:false); }
    }

    @for $i from 1 through $total-columns - 1 {
      .push#{-$i} { @include grid-column($push:$i, $collapse:null, $float:false); }
      .pull#{-$i} { @include grid-column($pull:$i, $collapse:null, $float:false); }
    }

    .column.medium-centered,
    .columns.medium-centered { @include grid-column($center:true, $collapse:null, $float:false); }

    .column.medium-uncentered,
    .columns.medium-uncentered {
      margin-#{$default-float}: 0;
      margin-#{$opposite-direction}: 0;
      float: $default-float !important;
    }

    .column.medium-uncentered.opposite,
    .columns.medium-uncentered.opposite {
      float: $opposite-direction !important;
    }

  }

}
```

Now you can use medium like you do the small and large grid.

https://gist.github.com/poeticninja/5985220

Answer (score 5):

With Foundation 4, all you need to do is include the grid-5 Sass or CSS file to enable a medium grid.

```
@import "foundation/components/grid-5";
```

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html#medium-grid

Comment: The medium grid is (experimentally) available, but I found out that the block-grid does not support the medium breakpoint in Foundation 4. I created a _block-grid-5.scss as a quick solution which you can find in this pull request: https://github.com/zurb/foundation/pull/2922

Answer (score 2):

Since version 4.3, Foundation has an (experimental) Medium Grid! You can find their breakpoints and details about how to activate it in their blog post [Foundation 4.3: Paving the Road to 5](http://zurb.com/article/1226/foundation-4-3-paving-the-road-to-5).

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class='row'>
    <div id='foo' class='large-4 medium-6 small-12 columns'>        
    </div>
</div>
```

scss

```
@mixin respond-to($media) {
  @if $media == small-mode {
    @media only screen and (max-width: 420px) { @content }
  }
  @else if $media == medium-mode {
    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) { @content }
  }
  @else if $media == large-mode {
    @media only screen and (max-width: 980px) { @content }
    }
  }
}
```

http://adioso.com/blog/

i didn't tried it yet but in the next few days i will try it and i will came up with more details